# How to increase value of a number on button press?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app to increase the value of a number on screen to the next number when the button is pressed. It is not working. I have given my Java and XML code below.

XML code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="200dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="0" />
```

Java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;

    protected int a = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }

    public void display(final int n) {
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText(n);
            }
        });
    }

    public void increment(View view) {
        a = a + 1;
        display(a);
    }
}
```

The button  is unreactive.

Comment: where you call display method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button, increase the value of `a`. Then pass the `a` to display method. Finally display the value to `textView`.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button btn;
        TextView txt;

        protected int a = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   a++;
                   display(a);
                }
            });

        }

        public void display(int n) {
            txt.setText("" + n);
            //txt.setText(n);
        }
}
```

Comment: @Priyanshu_rl I have edited the "display" method. Try with replacing that method.

Comment: @DHAVAL ASODARIYA The app works thank u  but i still don't get y it worked and others didnt ?

Comment: @Priyanshu_rl it is because textView unable to handle other data type except String. So I edited this line. `txt.setText("" + n);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment your counter and set new text

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;

    protected int a = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText(String.valueOf(++a));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am not mistake, we can not call `onClickListener in some method.
In any case, change the code in your button to the next one and it should work.

```
int a = 0;

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        a = a + 1;
        txt.setText(a);
    }
});
```

in this case, that code helps. becose it increases value a on 1, all time when we click on the button.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the problem is and how the code helps.

Comment: in this case, that code helps. becose it increases value `a` on `1`, all time when we click on the button.

Comment: You should add the explanation to your answer. Use the [edit] link, then explain what the problem with the initial code is and how your code solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

When you click the on the button, increase the value of a and display to the textView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;
    protected int a = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a++;
                txt.setText(a + "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```